# ERROR! The requested handler 'restart nginx' was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the listening handlers list

Tags: ansible

I have a simple role that only installs nginx with an restart handler but this does not work. I get the error: "ERROR! The requested handler 'restart nginx' was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the listening handlers list"

What am I doing wrong?

directory

```
test_handler
  handers 
    - main.yml
  tasks 
    - main.yml
```

handlers/main.yml

```
---
# handlers file for /ansible/roles/test_handler
- name: reload nginx
  service: name=nginx state=reloaded enabled=yes
  become: yes
  become_user: root

- name: restart nginx
  service: name=nginx state=restarted enabled=yes
  become: yes
  become_user: root
```

tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Install nginx
  yum: name=nginx state=latest update_cache=yes
  notify:
    - restart nginx
  become: yes
  become_user: root
```

Comment: I think you have to import the tasks. Something like `in main playbook

  handlers:
    - include_tasks: test/handlers/test-handler.yml`

Using import_tasks or include instead of include_tasks in ./role/x/handlers/main.yml or main playbook yml file seems to work with a simple role.

Answer (score 1):

Yes correct @user3511320 especially if the task is invoking role dependent tasks/handlers.
Instead of include tasks users 'roles' and invoke entire role.

```
Use:

    roles:
    - ../roles/foo

instead of:
 tasks:
  - include_tasks: ../../roles/foo/tasks/test.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was my playbook which called the role. I did this with include: not with roles.

Comment: Could you please add the details on how you changed your configuration to your answer, some code snippet. Might be useful for me, I have similar issues. Thanks.